# How can I return from an effect with ngrx / angular5 from a callback function?

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-effects

My effect has:

```
  @Effect()   /* sends request to httpService with params as login credentials on instance of loginAction. */
  login$: Observable<Action> = this.actions$
    .instanceOf(LoginActions.LoginAction)
    .switchMap(
      action => {
        return this.loginHttpService.login(action.payload)
          .map( (res: any) => {
                const firstName = res.firstName;
                const lastName = res.lastName;
                // const privileges = res.privileges
                const privileges = ['ViewDeliverableDefinitions', 'SubmitDeliverableInstances']
                this.tokenService.setPrivileges(privileges)
                console.log('observable')
                return Observable.create(observer => {
                  console.log('this is 1')
                  this.permissionsService.loadPermissions(privileges, () => {
                    console.log('this is 2')

                    // observer.next({
                    //   type: 'string'
                    // });
                    this.store.dispatch(new LoginActions.LoginSuccessAction({user: res}))
                    // return observer.complete();

                  })
                })
          })
          .catch( (e:any)  => {
            this.store.dispatch(new LoginActions.LoginFailureAction(true));

            return Observable.create(observer => {
              return observer.complete();
            }) 
        });
      });
```

However, nothing ever gets called from `Observer.create`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What do you mean by nothing gets called ? You should get in the catch only when there is an error in the request.

Comment: Instead of `map`, if you want to return another observable, you should use `flatMap` or `switchMap`

Comment: Why do you need to do so?

Comment: @Envil Because otherwise the original observable will emit another Observable, which in turn needs to be subscribed to. By using `switchMap`, we can chain the observables, so that only 1 subscribe is needed.

Comment: @AdrianFâciu, the `console.log('observable')` fires. But `this is 1` and `this is 2` do not

Comment: This doesn’t sound like a goof practice to chain the http requests to me.

Comment: If you want the observable to run, you have to subscribe to it.

Comment: @envil, can you please post an example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of things that need to be updated. First `map` needs to be a `switchMap` as previously suggested. This is because an `Effect` must return an `Observable` that emits an `Action`. Doing so will cause the inner observable to be subscribed to. Second, instead of dispatching the action manually, the Effect will do this for you and so you need to just emit a new action in each created observable.

Updated code (minus comments):

```js
@Effect()   /* sends request to httpService with params as login credentials on instance of loginAction. */
login$: Observable<Action> = this.actions$
  .instanceOf(LoginActions.LoginAction)
  .switchMap(
    action => {
      return this.loginHttpService.login(action.payload)
        .switchMap((res: any) => {
          const firstName = res.firstName;
          const lastName = res.lastName;
          const privileges = ['ViewDeliverableDefinitions', 'SubmitDeliverableInstances'];

          this.tokenService.setPrivileges(privileges);

          return new Observable<Action>(observer => {
            this.permissionsService.loadPermissions(privileges, () => {

              observer.next(new LoginActions.LoginSuccessAction({user: res}));
              observer.complete();
            });
          });
    })
    .catch( (e:any)  => {
      return Observable.of(new LoginActions.LoginFailureAction(true));
    });
```

Comment: Getting an error when I try that:

`Obervable<{}> is not assignable to type 'Observable<Action>`

Comment: You will need to update the created observable with the type information. I have updated my answer.

Comment: `Type Observable<{} | Action> is not assignable to type Observable<Action>`

Comment: What method is complaining about this? The `switchMap`, the `catch`? Does `LoginSuccessAction` implement `Action`?

Comment: It's complaining on line 26, which is `@Effect()`. And yes, `LoginSuccessAction` implements `Action`